# Linking multithreaded runtimes for GCC in Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, codeblocks, crt

Advice is all over the Internet that for multithreaded Win32 apps – at least for MS Visual Studio – you have to link with the multithreaded C runtime library instead of the single-threaded one (so LIBCMT.LIB or LIBCPMT.LIB instead of LIBC.LIB or LIBCP.LIB). I’m currently using Code::Blocks with the GCC Compiler, and I’m not sure if the above advice is even applicable, or how to change those link settings if it is. I can’t find any of the above files listed anywhere in the build settings in the IDE. If I call the “_beginthread” function in a simple test program, it seems to compile and run without any problem, but I’m not sure that proves anything. I can call the “printf” function from the new thread, and the output appears in the main console window. I don’t know if that’s correct behaviour or not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks Tim for your response. I don’t know where to find the compiler flags in this IDE – that’s part of the problem. The other part is I don’t know what to change when I do find them. But here’s my simple test program – I hope it’s helpful:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE ThreadHandle;

void RunThreadFunc(void *This) {
   printf("%s", "Squeak.\n\n");
   _endthread();
}

int main () {
   Sleep(2000);

   ThreadHandle = (HANDLE) _beginthread(RunThreadFunc, 0, NULL);

   //printf("%s", "Woo.\n\n");

   Sleep(2000);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code along with your current compiler flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of GCC shipped with Code::Blocks is TDM-GCC. This version of GCC uses the MinGW C runtime library, which is almost entirely built around the DLL version of Visual Studio 6 multithreaded C runtime, MSVCRT.DLL. (Note that MSVCRT.DLL is now considered part of the Windows operating system.)  There's no static library version of the MinGW runtime, whether multithreaded or not, so there is no equivalent to either LIBCMT.LIB or LIBC.LIB. It's the equivalent to linking with with MSVCRT.LIB.

On the other hand, GCC uses it's own C++ runtime library. The TDM-GCC release provides two versions of it, a static multithreaded version and a DLL multithreaded version.

So the advice you heard about using the multithreaded runtime libraries with Visual Studio doesn't apply. You don't have a choice, your GCC compiled projects will always be linked with the multithreaded runtimes. (Note that this is also true for modern versions of Visual Studio, they dropped support for the single threaded runtimes with Visual Studio 2005.)

Comment: Thanks very much, that’s very helpful! By the way, can you offer any references to support that answer, please?

Comment: @Entropy Not to anything authoritative for the significant claims. You can verify yourself that any application you create is linked with MSVCRT.DLL, but you'll need to refer to a copy of the Visual Studio 6 documentation, no longer online, to find an official statement that this is it's multithreaded CRT. TDM-GCC's documentation is almost non-existent and while it does mention that it provides two versions of the C++RT, and it does mention threading, it doesn't quite say the two C++RT versions are multithread safe: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/quirks

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to verify what my apps are linked with in this IDE – that’s why I posted this question after many hours of searching. By your definition, I have to assume that you’re not strictly an authority on the subject either, although you do seem to know what you’re talking about. I think it would be helpful to have links to other sources which also seem to know what they’re talking about, even if they are not strictly authoritative either. Thanks.

Comment: @Entropy I think then you're just going to have to take me at my word. I don't know of any source anywhere that says this outright. It's something you have to infer from various sources like those I referred to in my previous comment. If those verifiable facts aren't enough to convince you then there's really no point in me saying more. if this is really important to you might consider switching to another compiler that does make explicit the guarantees you're looking for.

Comment: This compiler already was the last resort for me, but I do believe your answer. I just wanted to be as sure as possible, that’s all. Thanks for your input!